# How to set class options that can have multiple values?

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, class-options, comma-separated-list

Title says it all, but here's an example: the KOMA-Script classes provide the option `toc` which can have multiple values that don't interfere with each other, like values that enable the Bibliography in the TOC and others that just influence the layout of the TOC. When I need several of these values for the class option `toc`, how can I pass them all together to `toc` without having to repeat `toc=` all the time?

What I have currently:

```
\documentclass[toc=listof, toc=bibliography, toc=flat]{scrbook}
```

Idea of what I'd like to have (but what does not work)

```
\documentclass[toc={listof, bibliography, flat}]{scrbook}
```

Is this somehow possible? If yes, how?

Comment: write a feature request to the author of the KOMA classes

Comment: Ah, so this depends on the class itself and not on some general Latex syntax?

Comment: yes, it depends on how the class reads and sets its options.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard LaTeX `\documentclass` syntax doesn't use `=` at all, just a comma separated list of values like `[12pt,twoside]` so

```
\documentclass[toc=listof, toc=bibliography, toc=flat]{article}
```

would just be three (undefined) options `toc=listof` , `toc=bibliography` and `toc=flat`
There is no mechanism for passing values to an option `toc`.

Some classes load `keyval` or similar packages and redefine `\documentclass` to use that so then your example passes the three values `listof`, `bibliography` and `flat` to the `toc` key defined by that class.

In your example `toc={listof, bibliography, flat}` the keyval parser will pass the single value 
`listof, bibliography, flat` to the `toc` key, but then it is up to the definition of that key in the class whether it treats this as an unknown value or whether it further processes it as a comma separated list.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I found for solving OP's problem is to introduce a new class file *xscrbook*. See below.

```
\ProvidesClass{xscrbook}[2013/01/17 v0.1 Extends KOMA-script-book class (AM)]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
\protected\def\scr@preprocessclassoptionslist#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \let#1\@empty
  \fi
  \ifx#1\@empty\else
    \begingroup
    \def\scr@tempa{}%
    \def\scr@tempb##1=##2=##3\scr@nil##4{%
      \ifx\relax##2\relax\else
        \def\scr@option{##1}%
        \edef\scr@value{\zap@space##2 \@empty}%
        ##4%
      \fi
    }%
    \@for\reserved@a:=#1\do{%
      \expandafter\scr@tempb\reserved@a==\scr@nil{%
        \@for\reserved@a:=\scr@value\do{%
          \edef\scr@tempa{%
            \scr@tempa\ifx\scr@tempa\@empty\else,\fi
            \scr@option=\reserved@a
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \edef\scr@tempa{\endgroup\def\noexpand#1{\scr@tempa}}%
    \scr@tempa
  \fi
}
\scr@preprocessclassoptionslist\@classoptionslist
\ifdefined\XKV@classoptionslist
  \scr@preprocessclassoptionslist\XKV@classoptionslist
\fi
\LoadClass{scrbook}

\endinput
```

Example

```
\documentclass[toc={listof, bibliography, flat}]{xscrbook}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Comment: You certainly can pass keyval options using the `\documentclass` line: this is standard in KOMA. What you have to watch is that expansion and space-stripping takes place.

Comment: What's with all the trailing % signs?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to proceed is described in the KOMA-Script documentation as

> Some options can have several values simultaneously. For such options, it is possible, with the help of \KOMAoption, to pass a list of values to a single option. The individual values are given as a comma-separated value list.

So, in your example:

```
\documentclass[any_option]{scrbook}
\KOMAoption{toc}{bibliography,listof,flat}
```

Please pay attention that, with biblatex, this was not enough to get the bibliography in the table of contents.
I had to use:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

or any equivalent command.

Enjoy!

Comment: welcome to TEXSE, could you please explain the differences of your answer with respect to the already existings ones?

Comment: @Raaja This is the correct answer, because all classes from KOMA-Script (and that this is used was already written in the question) can use command `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions` to define more class options. That commands can be used in the preamble or in the document ... I also added tag `koma-script` to the question ...

Comment: @Mensch I was not saying it is wrong per se, I was asking what the difference is. If you see David's already accepted answer, the solution is available.

Comment: @Raaja That question and answer are from 2013 (sic!). Today, 2019, KOMA-Script is able to handle more that on value per class option as mentioned in this answer ...

Comment: @Raaja David's answer is the explanation of the mechanism that is hidden in the KOMA-Script bundle and, as Mensch mentioned, it was written a few years ago. As there was no update and I looked exactely for the same problem 2 hours ago I put here the right process. Hope this helps :)
By the way, thanks for the welcome :)