# Koma script multiple key=value

Tags: koma-script

I am using Koma-script for a report.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,12pt,a4paper,toc=bibnumbered,numbers=endperiod]{scrreprt}
```

I would like to give multiple option to "toc" option such as bibnumbered, flat, chapterentrywithdots etc. instead of just one.

How can I do this?

I am a newbie so please bare with me...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer exatcly what I asked in the following link.

[How to set class options that can have multiple values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93884/how-to-set-class-options-that-can-have-multiple-values)

However, the accepted answer ignores what is working in the question. Following syntax solved my problem. Simply repeating the additional options...

```
\documentclass[titlepage,
12pt,
a4paper,
toc=bibnumbered,
toc=flat,
toc=chapterentrywithdots,
numbers=endperiod]{scrreprt}
```

Answer (score 0):

Koma-script documentation states:

L A TEX allows users to pass class options as a comma-separated list of keywords in the optional argument to \documentclass. In addition to being passed to the class, these options are also passed on to all packages that can understand them. Users can also pass a similar comma-separated list of keywords in the optional argument of \usepackage. KOMA - Script extends the option mechanism for the KOMA - Script classes and some packages with further options. **Thus most KOMA - Script options can also take a value, so an option does not necessarily take the form option , but can also take the form option =value** . Except for this difference, \documentclass and \usepackage in KOMA - Script function as described in [Tea05b] or any introduction to L A TEX, for example [OPHS11].